# Is it not recommended to change the object of meditation during a short session?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-breath

Sometimes I tend to switch my attention from the nostrils to the "up and down" of the chest/stomach

It depends on how well I'm breathing (I have serious problem with the nostrils, it can only be 100% fixed in a surgery)

I do prefer the nostrils, however this change is commom everytime it becomes impossible to keep breathing throught them (so I swith to the mounth and focus on the chest)

Is this switch not recommended for any reason, for instance, is this a problem to reach right concentration?

Answer (score 3):

### The simple answer is it is not. Don't change it.

- If you concentrate on breathing for a while you mind will play tricks
  like, Now the it is time to change the session but it is not. Buddha
  has taught not to fall for that kind of feelings.
- Even if you try to master elements it the same. don't fall for that
  feelings. Possibly if you do it for some time it is likely that you
  will get fame, but it is temporary that is a test for you. If you
  simply stop everything fades away sometimes you will fall than you
  were before.

  **Read VipasanaBavana from Balangoda Anananda Mithree thero for more info**

Answer (score 2):

Use the Columella or [Philtrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philtrum). This is as taught by Webu Sayadaw, U Ba Khin and Goenkaji. This is very effective.

Also p37 of [With Each & Every Breath: A Guide to Meditation](http://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/withEachAndEveryBreath_v131019.pdf) and Method 2 in [Keeping the Breath in Mind](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/lee/inmind.html) gives additional places.

If you change your position your Samadhi. To make your Samadhi stronger you must choose:

1. A small area
2. Continuously bring the mind to this chosen area
3. Sustain the mind in the chosen area as long as possible

In the Buddhist path Samadhi is important. You cannot bake a cake without all or without the ingredients in appropriate quantities. Without Samadhi your wisdom shall be shallow.

- [What is the Interpretation of Parimukham in the context of Buddhist Meditation?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2518/what-is-the-interpretation-of-parimukham-in-the-context-of-buddhist-meditation/2524)
- See the section on Ānāpānapabbaṃ in:

  - [Discourses on Satipatthana Sutta](http://www.vridhamma.org/Discourses-on-Satipatthana-Sutta) - S. N. Goenka
  - [The Great Discourse on the Establishing of Awareness](http://www.tipitaka.org/stp-pali-eng-parallel) - VRI translation
- [The Essential Practice Part II](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/webu/wheel384.html) and [The Essential Practice Part I](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/webu/wheel375.html) by Webu Sayadaw